# How screen sharing feature is work in safari?

Tags: macos, safari, twilio, twilio-api, screensharing

I am using https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/migrating-1x-2x for the app.

Screen sharing is working fine in chrome and firefox but that is not working in safari.

So, anyone can help with that, How screen sharing feature is working in safari?

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

[Safari doesn't yet support the screen sharing APIs](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_mediadevices_getdisplaymedia) that the other browsers do, so it won't work in Safari right now. I can't find any documentation that would make that available through a Safari extension either.

Comment: Thanks for this response. Suppose I wants to use this feature in Safari, is there any other idea about this?

Comment: The only way I can imagine you could get this to work in Safari is by building an extension that makes the screen sharing possible. On a quick search I couldn't find any documentation about that, but I would imagine it's possible. I would recommend you look into the Safari extensions APIs and see what is available.